# Select and order parent record by child attribute Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two ruby classes, Jobs and Listings.

Listing attributes: `job_id`, `live_date`, `is_active`

Job attributes: `title`, `description`, `category`

If I want to retrieve the details of 2 jobs from a single category where the associated listing live date's are the 2 most recent and the listing is active is there an efficient one-liner of Ruby that I could use?

At the moment I am looking at looping over things multiple times and I imagine there might be a more efficient way of doing this.

**Desired Output**

Two job results where the listing is both active and the live_dates are the most recent ones. (A job in this instance will only ever have 1 active listing.)

> ```
> @jobs = [
>   {
>     title: 'Job Title',
>     description: 'Job Description',
>     category: 'marketing'
>   },
>   {
>     title: 'Job Title',
>     description: 'Job Description',
>     category: 'marketing'
>   }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data and desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the following. It's untested so might need a tweak or two, but should return the two `jobs` you've requested:

```
Job.eager_load(:listings).order("listings.live_date DESC").where(category: "your category", listings: { active: true }).first(2)
```

To break this down:

- `eager_load` preloads your listings, so you can use them in your query. If you're not using them for anything else, `outer_joins` might be a better choice and more performant
- `order` applies directions to the `ORDER BY` element of the generated SQL
- the `where` clause lets you query the `jobs`, as well as the associated `listings` by passing the hash specified as a value
- `first(2)` returns the first two records, in this case the desired ones due to the order in place

Comment: If you're using `.includes` with where you might as well use `.eager_load` since `.includes`  defers to `.eager_load`  in that case.

Comment: Thanks @max, much appreciated - I've updated to use this approach. For a quick point of clarity on my part, `includes` chooses between `eager_load` and `preload` depending on what's required. Does that sound right? Are there additional advantages to be gained -- other that being explicit, which is sufficient -- by directly using `eager_load`?

Comment: No its pretty much just clarity. However you can’t replace it with joins since joins does a left inner join - you want .outer_joins

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Max and SRack. This answer provided the output I was looking for but i've updated my question with the desired output so that it's more clear for people looking in the future. Thanks again :)

Comment: Welcome, glad to help out @TomPinchen.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your requirements right, you need to get the two most recent listings of an entire category of Jobs, not just the most recent 2 Listings of a single job?

For my part, i always prefer to encapsulate model-related logic within the model (for DRY and MVC reasons), so usually i work with [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
class Listing
  belongs_to :job

  scope :is_active, -> { where(is_active: true) }
  scope :ordered_by_live_date -> { order(live_date: desc }
end

class Job
  has_many :listings

  def most_recent_category_listings(limit)
    # If you just need the most recent listings of this job,
    # remove .include and .where and rename Listing to listings
    Listing.include(:jobs).where(jobs: {category: self.category}).is_active.ordered_by_live_date.limit limit
  end
end
```

Note: Not tested, i am writing this just out of the top of my head, didn't do any Ruby in a while